# Express invokes router.use before router.param?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm wondering why does Express call router.param after router.use here?

Similar behavior with using `router.all` instead of `router.use`.

How can I get express to invoke params before calling any other middlwares?

```
const router = express.Router();

router.param("logNumber", (req, res, next, value) => {
  console.log("1 Called at", Date.now());
  next();
});

router.use((req, res, next) => {
  console.log("2 Called at", Date.now());
  next();
});
```

Console output

```
2 Called at 1645747636698
1 Called at 1645747636707
```

Comment: Why does the execution order matter?

Comment: I'm planning on using middleware with `router.use` that depends on path parameters parsed by `router.param`. e.g. in above example, the parameter `logNumber` will be parsed from string to integer, and then validated by looking up database. Then the middleware will use this parameter to do other things.